# How do I use the depth value from DepthMiddleware?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have a broad crawler that recursively travels websites, and I wanted to implemented a tier system which increments as the webpages gets further away from the original, seed url.

For example, if I started with `stackoverflow.com`, any links that can be visited from `http://stackoverflow.com` will have a tier value of 1 while the `stackoverflow.com` will have a tier value of 0 for being a seed url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The depth level of a response is available via `response.meta['depth']`.